# Lock between function calls

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 functions on my aspx.cs class:

**First function:**

```
...
if (pos == 1) {
  Change(0);
  ShowModal("blablablabla");
}
else {
   Change(1);
   ShowModal("bleblebleble");
}
...
```

**Second function:**

```
private void Change(int val) {
    if (ConfigFile.Inst.IsForm)
        ChangePositionForm(val);
    else
        ChangePositionButton(val);
}
```

First function is called in a foreach loop (in another aspx.cs file):

```
foreach (DataListItem it in datalist.Items) {
    FirstFunction(it.FindControl("val"));
}
```

I need to control that the calls to the first function do not run until the previous call has finished executing.

Thanks you.

Comment: foreach does not continue until the previous call has finished.

Comment: That's what i thought but.. The result is not what I expected... I'll continue looking for the solution..Thanks you.

Comment: Do you call anything async?